# Smoking oven and a flaming torch

Tags: genesis

In Genesis 15:17 (NASB)

> Now it came about, when the sun had set, that it was very dark, and behold, a **smoking oven and a flaming torch** appeared which passed between these pieces.

Please explain the smoking oven and a flaming torch. Is God carrying these items? How do they represent God?

I have several commentaries, and on line helps. I have read those with understanding. I am looking for a more detailed and in-depth answer.

Comment: Hi Joey Adair, welcome! Fire is often associated with the presence of God (Exodus, Deuteronomy, ...)